# auto.arima function gives wrong estimation

Tags: r, autoregressive-models

I will need to estimate the order of the best fitting ARMA(p,q) model for my data. I planned on using the auto.arima() function. Before actually applying this function to my real data I tested it on a simulated ARMA(2,2) model but auto.arima tells me ARMA(0,0) is the best fitting model. Am I doing something wrong?

My R code is:

```
    arma.sim<-arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.9,-.2),ma=c(-.7,.1)),n=100)
    auto.arima(arma.sim, ic = "bic", stepwise = FALSE, stationary = TRUE, 
               trace=TRUE, approximation = FALSE, d=0)
```

and the output is:

```
 ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean     : 285.6369
 ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean : 290.2392
 ARIMA(0,0,1) with zero mean     : 290.211
 ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean : 294.8129
 ARIMA(0,0,2) with zero mean     : 294.5108
 ARIMA(0,0,2) with non-zero mean : 299.1143
 ARIMA(0,0,3) with zero mean     : 299.1079
 ARIMA(0,0,3) with non-zero mean : 303.7112
 ARIMA(0,0,4) with zero mean     : 303.4891
 ARIMA(0,0,4) with non-zero mean : 308.0936
 ARIMA(0,0,5) with zero mean     : 306.2664
 ARIMA(0,0,5) with non-zero mean : 310.8631
 ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean     : 290.2075
 ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean : 294.8092
 ARIMA(1,0,1) with zero mean     : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,1) with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,2) with zero mean     : 298.9777
 ARIMA(1,0,2) with non-zero mean : 303.581
 ARIMA(1,0,3) with zero mean     : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,3) with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,4) with zero mean     : 307.8321
 ARIMA(1,0,4) with non-zero mean : 312.4367
 ARIMA(2,0,0) with zero mean     : 294.4807
 ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean : 299.0844
 ARIMA(2,0,1) with zero mean     : 298.9845
 ARIMA(2,0,1) with non-zero mean : 303.5879
 ARIMA(2,0,2) with zero mean     : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,3) with zero mean     : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,3) with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(3,0,0) with zero mean     : 299.0557
 ARIMA(3,0,0) with non-zero mean : 303.659
 ARIMA(3,0,1) with zero mean     : 303.5876
 ARIMA(3,0,1) with non-zero mean : 308.1908
 ARIMA(3,0,2) with zero mean     : Inf
 ARIMA(3,0,2) with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(4,0,0) with zero mean     : 303.5521
 ARIMA(4,0,0) with non-zero mean : 308.1561
 ARIMA(4,0,1) with zero mean     : 308.0647
 ARIMA(4,0,1) with non-zero mean : 312.6687
 ARIMA(5,0,0) with zero mean     : 307.3978
 ARIMA(5,0,0) with non-zero mean : 311.999



 Best model: ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean     

Series: arma.sim 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean 

sigma^2 estimated as 0.9728:  log likelihood=-140.52
AIC=283.03   AICc=283.07   BIC=285.64
```

Comment: Are you sure this is bad behavior? Maybe your data is composed just of noise.

Comment: arima.sim should simulate an ARMA(2,2) model and not just noise

Comment: @Sunny I noticed that, different results under different seeds. Firstly, ``bic`` often tends to under-estimate the order of the model. You could try ``aic``, but it would often overestimate. On the other hand, it is often the case that ARMA(n,k) may have a AR(x) or MA(y) representation, or the roots may cancel themselves out. So estimated ARMA(5,0,0) results may also be not-surprising.

Comment: As for the unit-roots, for your simulated data (i,e., with ``set.seed(129)``, try ``Arima(arma.sim, order = c(2,0,2)) %>% plot`` and notice the unit-root of the inverse MA roots. Hence the ``Inf`` values in the trace of your estimation

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better way to estimate p and q of the model? In the end p and q are supposed to be estimated for several long data sets. So looking at the acf and pacf each time would not work.